# Example of Background Pages to Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read the developer documentation at Google developer center for clarify this question, but it did not help.

The question is... can someone give me a pratical example of why I should use this kind of resource? Code please!

Link that I'm looking: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

At the end of this page there is an example, but it doesn't work or I'm doing a mistake.

In addiction, at image.html file present at example, they put a inline script, but it is forbbiden by Google Chrome, why they do that?

Comment: Background page is needed when you can't do something without it. If you can, you don't need the background page. Also, the samples in the documentation are outdated. See the dedicated [samples gallery](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: Thank you for more recents example links.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch

Comment: I've read this documentation too @JoshLee

Comment: think that I discovered the reason why I'm trouble. I was using background pages with default_popup, and when I use default_popup, the background not work!